# JavaScript, Django, and Google App Engine - Replace Text

Tags: javascript, python, django, google-app-engine, str-replace

My goal is to associate a tooltip (containing a definition) to certain words on the client side using JS.

The text is generated with Django/Python (from a GAE datastore).

To accomplish this, I need to scan a block of text for multiple key words that require definitions and dynamically create a html 'title' for the tooltip.

I have succesfully done this for one key word at a time, however, I seem to be unable to do a search for and replace multiple values within the same block of text (when I try to accomplish with a django forloop, the entire original string appears once for each replace command - see below). 

My code:

```
    var str="<p>Paragraph of text containing key words such as test1 and test2!  </p>";
    {% for i in thing %}
    document.write(str.replace(/{{i.word}}/gi, "<strong><a title='{{i.tooltip}}'> {{i.word}}</a></strong>"));
    {% endfor %}
```

This results in:

"Paragraph of text containing key words such as **keyword1** and keyword2!

Paragraph of text containing key words such as keyword1 and **keyword2**!"

My desired output is:

"Paragraph of text containing key words such as **keyword1** and **keyword2**!"

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, I have a very limited knowledge in JS.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to simply build up the string within the Django for loop, replacing on it each time, then only outputting it at the end:

```
{% for i in thing %}
str = str.replace(/{{i.word}}/gi, "<strong><a title='{{i.tooltip}}'> {{i.word}}</a></strong>"));
{% endfor %}
document.write(str);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This has allowed me to make some headway. The text no longer repeats each time, however, only a tooltip for the last i.word appears. None of the others do. This is because you are replacing the definition of string each time. I tried appending it, however, it duplicates again >.<

Comment: No, the code is correct - you do want to replace the definition of `str` each time. Have a look at the page source to see the generated javascript, and perhaps put some alert statements (or better, `console.debug()` if you have Firebug installed) to see how `str` is built up.